# Rename files in subfolders, move them to parent folder and delete subfolder

Tags: command-line, scripts

Currently doing some cleanup work and I'm struggling to rename my files accordingly.

I currently have it akin to this (Names are just placeholders, there are a lot more than alpha and beta):

```
└── Project/
    ├── alpha/
    │   ├── alpha1/
    │   │   ├── file1
    │   │   └── file2
    │   └── alpha2/
    │       ├── file1
    │       └── file2
    └── beta/
        ├── beta1/
        │   ├── file1
        │   └── file2
        └── beta2/
            ├── file1
            └── file2
```

And would like it to be like this:

```
└── Project/
    ├── alpha/
    │   ├── alpha1_file1
    │   ├── alpha1_file2
    │   ├── alpha2_file1
    │   └── alpha2_file2
    └── beta/
        ├── beta1_file1
        ├── beta1_file2
        ├── beta2_file1
        └── beta2_file2
```

How could I achieve this? Help appreciated and thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash`(*The default user shell in Ubuntu*) [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), it can be done from within the `Project` directory with e.g.:

```bash
for d in */*/
  do
  for f in "${d}"*
    do
    [[ -f "${f}" ]] && echo mv -nv -- "${f}" "${f%/*}_${f##*/}"
    done
  rmdir -v "${d}"
  done
```

or as a one-liner:

```bash
for d in */*/; do for f in "${d}"*; do [[ -f "${f}" ]] && echo mv -nv -- "${f}" "${f%/*}_${f##*/}"; done; rmdir -v "${d}"; done
```

`echo` is for a safe dry-run and `rmdir` will only remove empty directories and error otherwise ... Please, see demonstration below:

```bash
ubuntu@DESKTOP:~/test$ tree Project/
Project/
├── alpha
│   ├── alpha1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── alpha2
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
└── beta
    ├── beta1
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── beta2
        ├── file1
        └── file2

6 directories, 8 files
ubuntu@DESKTOP:~/test$ cd Project/
ubuntu@DESKTOP:~/test/Project$ for d in */*/; do for f in "${d}"*; do [[ -f "${f}" ]] && mv -nv -- "${f}" "${f%/*}_${f##*/}"; done; rmdir -v "${d}"; done
renamed 'alpha/alpha1/file1' -> 'alpha/alpha1_file1'
renamed 'alpha/alpha1/file2' -> 'alpha/alpha1_file2'
rmdir: removing directory, 'alpha/alpha1/'
renamed 'alpha/alpha2/file1' -> 'alpha/alpha2_file1'
renamed 'alpha/alpha2/file2' -> 'alpha/alpha2_file2'
rmdir: removing directory, 'alpha/alpha2/'
renamed 'beta/beta1/file1' -> 'beta/beta1_file1'
renamed 'beta/beta1/file2' -> 'beta/beta1_file2'
rmdir: removing directory, 'beta/beta1/'
renamed 'beta/beta2/file1' -> 'beta/beta2_file1'
renamed 'beta/beta2/file2' -> 'beta/beta2_file2'
rmdir: removing directory, 'beta/beta2/'
ubuntu@DESKTOP:~/test/Project$ tree
.
├── alpha
│   ├── alpha1_file1
│   ├── alpha1_file2
│   ├── alpha2_file1
│   └── alpha2_file2
└── beta
    ├── beta1_file1
    ├── beta1_file2
    ├── beta2_file1
    └── beta2_file2

2 directories, 8 files
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ tree Project/
Project/
├── alpha
│   └── alpha1
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
└── beta
    └── beta1
        ├── file1
        └── file2

4 directories, 4 files
```

```
rename -n 's@(Project/[^/]+)/(\w+\d+)/(file\d+)@$1/$2_$3@' ./Project/*/*/*
rmdir ./Project/*/*
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.

##### Output

```
rename(Project/alpha/alpha1/file1, Project/alpha/alpha1_file1)
rename(Project/alpha/alpha1/file2, Project/alpha/alpha1_file2)
rename(Project/beta/beta1/file1, Project/beta/beta1_file1)
rename(Project/beta/beta1/file2, Project/beta/beta1_file2)
```

Comment: Thanks, though as I said there are a lot more alpha and betas than just two, and manually renaming them would take way too long

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks! Sadly it doesn't seem to do anything the way you posted it; heres a screenshot of my terminal: https://i.vgy.me/M2MTQR.png

Comment: Have you tested that rename is the perl version that I explain in my link?

Comment: rename --version

Comment: Yes, I installed it according to their instructions, with rename --version I get ```/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.10```

Comment: @JeromeStephan you need to remove `-n` to actual perform the operations

Answer (score 0):

Using the contributed `zmv` module in `zsh`:

```
 % autoload -Uz zmv

 % zmv -v -Q 'Project/*/*/*(.N)' '$f:h_$f:t'
mv -- Project/alpha/alpha1/file1 Project/alpha/alpha1_file1
mv -- Project/alpha/alpha1/file2 Project/alpha/alpha1_file2
mv -- Project/alpha/alpha2/file1 Project/alpha/alpha2_file1
mv -- Project/alpha/alpha2/file2 Project/alpha/alpha2_file2
mv -- Project/beta/beta1/file1 Project/beta/beta1_file1
mv -- Project/beta/beta1/file2 Project/beta/beta1_file2
mv -- Project/beta/beta2/file1 Project/beta/beta2_file1
mv -- Project/beta/beta2/file2 Project/beta/beta2_file2
```

The `-Q` switch turns on the bare glob qualifier `(.N)` which matches only plain files, so that it will not attempt to move any subdirectories. The replacement pattern uses history-style **h**ead and **t**ail modifiers.

Now we just need to remove the empty directories:

```
 % rmdir -v Project/*/*(/^F)
rmdir: removing directory, 'Project/alpha/alpha1'
rmdir: removing directory, 'Project/alpha/alpha2'
rmdir: removing directory, 'Project/beta/beta1'
rmdir: removing directory, 'Project/beta/beta2'
```

leaving

```
 % tree Project
Project
├── alpha
│   ├── alpha1_file1
│   ├── alpha1_file2
│   ├── alpha2_file1
│   └── alpha2_file2
└── beta
    ├── beta1_file1
    ├── beta1_file2
    ├── beta2_file1
    └── beta2_file2

2 directories, 8 files
```